# MySQL upgrade to 8

Tags: mysql

I have tried and followed a few MySQL upgrade posts to (what should be a simple task).

https://tastethelinux.com/upgrade-mysql-server-from-5-7-to-8-ubuntu-18-04/N

The whole thing is now screwed and I cannot access MySQL on this server.

Advice please on to how reset this and access the server remotely - I noted that there was no longer a cnf file after running commands on this post.

Basically what I am asking is how to fully purge my sql and install it with version 8 and find the cnf file to make it remote accessible

Comment: Please start with your OS & release details; also check & correct your URL; as you tried following a "*Ooops! That page can't be found*" set of instructions isn't helpful.

Comment: Well I did not follow a set of instructions on a failed webpage - it was there

Comment: Can you upgrade your OS?  If you go up to Ubuntu 20.04, you will get MySQL 8, according to [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mysql-server) list.  I wouldn't suggest what you're doing.  I don't care if there's a web page on some web site that says you can do it...  MySQL might have a lot of dependencies and you're more than likely to end up with a non-working system...

Comment: @Ray perfect idea, I guess at some point I stuffed the system

Comment: @Ray - can you post this as an answer so I can select it. Additionally the cnf file is not needed - this post provides correct remote access info. BTW neber allow 'root' remote access, create a specific user for this. Use root temporarily for this if you wish to use a tool such as Workbench to create a 'remote' user, but then remove '%' for root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On occasion, you can install a package from another (more recent) version of Ubuntu.  But the more complicated the package, the more dependencies it will have.  And upgrading just that package will cause a cascading effect that will require you to install these dependencies.  And you're more likely to break your system than get the upgrade you want.

Of course, this is not specific to Ubuntu.  If you had Microsoft Windows from 2011, no one would expect you to be able to run Microsoft Office from 2021.  And we can't expect either Microsoft or Ubuntu to permit this level of compatibility -- it would be a lot of work.

My feeling is that MySQL probably has a lot of dependencies.  Looking at [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mysql-server) list, it looks like MySQL 8 is part of Ubuntu 20.04.  It might be more work and you could affect other systems, but in the long run, upgrading your OS will give you a more stable system than upgrading just MySQL.  Especially if you think you've made a mistake already.